# Bash: simplify variable replacement/upper-casing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Is there any way to cleanly simplify this into a single line?

```
# e.g. ARG='--some-arg'

ARG=${ARG/--/}    # some-arg
ARG=${ARG//-/_}   # some_arg
ARG=${ARG^^}      # SOME_ARG
```

I'm hoping for a syntax that allows you to include multiple "directives" at once, for instance (made up):

```
ARG=${ARG^^;/--/;//-/_}
```

Comment: Technically `ARG=${ARG/--/}; ARG=${ARG//-/_}; ARG=${ARG^^}` is a single line, but I guess you don't want this. "Simplify into a single assignment" may be a better phrase for what you want.

Comment: Yeah, just wondering if it can be made less redundant.

Comment: ```ARG=$(echo ${ARG^^} | sed "s/--//" | sed "s/-/_/")```
But this is less readable than your 3 lines!

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll just leave it as is because yes, it seems there isn't a way to combine them.